# Aggregating time to a defined slot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which has a few weeks of `2`minute resolution data:

`df.dtypes`

```
time_stamp      datetime64[ns]
Day_name                object 
x                     int64
y                   int64
```

`df.head`

```
time_stamp             Day_name   x   y  
0 2017-05-17 14:28:35  Wednesday  100 200   
1 2017-05-17 14:30:32  Wednesday  300 400
```

I want to aggregate the metrics `x` and `y` and find their average for the average '15' minute period. I originally had an epoch metric, but I've converted this to the `datetime` shown above.

```
time_stamp             Day_name   x   y        15_min_slot
    0 2017-05-17 14:28:35  Wednesday  100 200  14:15
    1 2017-05-17 14:30:32  Wednesday  300 400  14:30
```

How do i do this?

I can find the hour via:

`df['hour'] = df['time_stamp'].dt.hour`

`df['minute'] = df['time_stamp'].dt.minute`

What I'll eventually do is then:

`output = df.groupby(['15_min_slot'],as_index=False)['x'].mean()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html), in combination with the `freq` argument, i.e:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key=df['time_stamp'], freq='15T')).mean()
```

Comment: Quick question - is it possible to do the sample for any `15`min period, over the entire dataset? So basically, one day worth of average 15min periods?

Comment: Then make a new column with only the hour and minutes (i.e. `df['new_column'] = df['time_stamp'].hour` or a variant of that

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `resample`:

First create a datetimeindex for your dataframe

```
df = df.set_index('time_stamp')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Then use `resample` with `15T` and `mean`:

```
df.resample('15T').mean()
```

Output:

```
                       x    y
time_stamp                   
2017-05-17 14:15:00  100  200
2017-05-17 14:30:00  300  400
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.resample()` as in

```
df.resample('15T').mean()
```

The list of options can be found here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases